# List installed packages in Debian from a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have a system that will not boot as /usr has been destroyed and I would like to get  a list of installed packages before re-installing. I know that it's possible to get this using dpkg or apt, but I cannot run those.

Where in the filesystem is this information stored and what's the best way to get a list of installed apps from the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for /var/lib/dpkg/status.

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at `/var/apt/cache/packages` where all downloaded packages are cached. However, if a package was deleted, it would still remain there. And one more important thing: if you have already done a `apt-get clean` then it has already been cleaned.